# Return inside PHP recursive function

Tags: php, recursion

I am writing a PHP recursive function to get data using their value form an array. So here is function what I am trying to build:

```
  function test($menu) {

    $url = "test.com/accounts/overview/";

    foreach($menu as $data) {

      if( is_array($data) and array_key_exists("t_link", $data) and $data["t_link"] === $url ) {

        return $data["t_icon"]; 

      } else if(is_array($data)) {

        test($data);

      }
    }
  }

echo test($menu);
```

The first condition only true for one time as of my array and the `return` must return the value & terminate the function, isn't it?. But why it is noting return? Also, if I use `echo $data["t_icon"];` instead of `return $data["t_icon"];` it is showing the correct result: `fa fa-book`.

This is the array from where I am trying to get the `t_icon` value based on the `t_link` value. The condition is if `t_link` value has `test.com/accounts/overview/` then it will return the `fa fa-book`

```
$menu = array ();
$menu["Dashboard"] = array (
    "t_link"    => "test.com",
    "t_icon"    => "fa fa-dashboard"
  );
  $menu["Accounts"] = array (
    "t_link"    => "test.com/accounts",
    "t_icon"    => "fa fa-books"
  );
  $menu["Accounts"]["Overview"] = array (
    "t_link"    => "test.com/accounts/overview/",
    "t_icon"    => "fa fa-book"  <<-- This value I want to get
  );
```

I searched a lot of and got this that I should return the function inside the second condition like this `return test($data);`. But it also not working. Thank you.

Comment: Without the return it runs the function but does not return anything.   You want to return a result.  You might have other bugs, try using a debugger or adding logging.

Comment: sidenote: recursion is cool. Really. Especially for compilers. However function calls are very slow in php, and loops are much more faster - even in C. Not to mention the memory needs and the nested function limitation(lesser bad). So unless if you really must solve it recursion, it's better to use a well structured array instead.

Comment: Thank you sir @DavidHlavati, Actually it is a menu array.

Comment: @DaveS, other bugs? Can please give me a example?

Comment: "function calls are very slow in php" @DavidHlavati care to back up your claim with a credible source? I have never once heard of this.

Comment: Please be so kind and prove it, that I'm wrong. I love learning new things about programming

Comment: A spontaneous reaction is. Do you need recursion here? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: "function calls are very slow in php" . That is true for all languages if you make bad descisions inside the functions  ;-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, Recursion is not necessary if get desire value without using it. I want the `t_icon` value based the `t_link` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because a function ***should*** always have a return value - in **recursion** it is **required**:

```
function test($menu) {

    $url = "test.com/accounts/overview/";

    foreach($menu as $data) {

      if( is_array($data) && 
      isset($data["t_link"]) && 
      $data["t_link"] === $url ) {        
          return $data["t_icon"]; 
      } 
      else if (is_array($data)) {
          $result = test($data); //Get result back from function

          //If it's NOT NULL call the function again (test($data))
          //
          //(down below returns null when looped through 
          //everything recursively)
          //
          if ($result !== null) { 
              return $result;
          }
      }

    }

    return null;
}
```

---

**Here's another way of achieving what you want OOP-style:**

The idea behind this solution is to create a two-level array (no more, no less nr of levels) and grab data from that new array.

```
class Searcher {
    private $new_arr = array();
    private $icon = '';

    //array_walk_recursive goes through your array recursively
    //and calls the getdata-method in the class. This method creates
    //a new array with strings (not arrays) from supplied $array ($menu in your case)
    public function __construct($array, $search_url) {
        array_walk_recursive($array, array($this, 'getdata'));     
        $key = array_search($search_url, $this->new_arr['t_link']);
        $this->icon = $this->new_arr['t_icon'][$key];
    }

    public function geticon() {
        return $this->icon;
    }

    public function getdata($item, $key) {
        if (!is_array($item)) {
            $this->new_arr[$key][] = $item;    
        }        
    }

}

//Implementation (usage) of above class
$search = new Searcher($menu, 'test.com/accounts/overview/');
$icon = $search->geticon();
echo 'ICON=' . $icon; //Would echo out 'fa fa-book'
```

**Further explanation:**

Based on your `$menu` - array the class will create an array like this (`$this->new_arr`):

```
Array
(
    [t_link] => Array
        (
            [0] => test.com
            [1] => test.com/accounts
            [2] => test.com/accounts/overview/
        )

    [t_icon] => Array
        (
            [0] => fa fa-dashboard
            [1] => fa fa-books
            [2] => fa fa-book
        )

)
```

---

All the keys are related to eachother in the new array. This is set with `$this->new_arr[$key][] = $item;`  within the `getdata()` method. This is based on the fact it must be equal number of `t_link`-keys and `t_icon`-keys in the array.

**Because of this:**

```
$this->new_arr[0]['t_link'] is related to $this->new_arr[0]['t_icon'];
$this->new_arr[1]['t_link'] is related to $this->new_arr[1]['t_icon'];
$this->new_arr[2]['t_link'] is related to $this->new_arr[2]['t_icon'];
etc.. (not more in your example)
```

---

When having this code:

```
$key = array_search($search_url, $this->new_arr['t_link']);
```

it would give the key **2** if you have supplied `$search_url` to **test.com/accounts/overview/**

Therefore:

```
$this->icon = $this->new_arr['t_icon'][$key];
```

is set to fa fa-book

Comment: Thanks @bestprogrammerintheworld, Looks like you have tried best way to solve my problem. I have solved my problem another way. But I still did not understand, why my above code is not working? Because, The first condition only true for one time and the return must terminate the function, isn't it?

Comment: I have updated answer and I explain why your code is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call a function inside a function, you have to return the value of the function, here is the fix: (added "return" before test($data);)

```
 function test($menu) {

    $url = "test.com/accounts/overview/";

    foreach($menu as $data) {

      if( is_array($data) and array_key_exists("t_link", $data) and $data["t_link"] == $url ) {
        return $data["t_icon"]; 
      } else if(isset($data["Overview"])) {
        return test($data);
      }
    }
  }
```

Also, all three cases, they both array so `return test($data);` will stop the foreach then `$menu["Accounts"]["Overview"]` will never be check.

Comment: Thank you sir, Please check my last line of question. I have also tried with your way. But got fail.

Comment: @RoyalHarun because using return will stop the foreach at `$menu["Dashboard"]` while echo will not, you have problem with your logic, not the code

Comment: How it exit on `$menu["Dashboard"]` while it has this condition `$data["t_link"] === $url`. Okay no problem. Can you please show me the fix?

Comment: Not a ideal solution. The array just for an example. the `$menu["Accounts"]["Overview"]` can be `$menu["Accounts"]["Create"]`, `$menu["Accounts"]["Other"]` so so....

Comment: @RoyalHarun that why I said it's because of your logic, I just can show you where is wrong while I do not know what your data could be, in this case you have to find the best logic so seconds call of test() will not break the foreach loop.